# Error: probably unsupported type when saving json.dumps() output to sqlite using Flask-sqlalchmey

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sqlalchemy to store data in SQLlite via restapi

The value of column "val" is fetched from a 3rd party package which somewhere in their code returns the output of json.dumps("london") in the case below. Json.dumps() is used heavily in that package.

It works well with Postgres but fails to store data in sqlite with error below

```
"(sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.\n[SQL: INSERT INTO area (area_type, val, person_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]\n[parameters: ('city', ('\"london\"',), 1)]\n(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)",
```

How can I fix this error when using sqlite?

Comment: Looks like you or the package has made a 1-tuple out of the result of `json.dumps()` and that is passed as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! My eyes completely ignored the comma in my code.... thus converting string into tuple